# Read-only exception in trigger

Tags: trigger, update, after

> Execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only

```
trigger Contact_details_on_task on Task (before insert) {
list<task> t=[select whoid,description from task];
string iid;
    set<id> s=new set<id>();
    set<id> whoid=new set<id>();
    for(task t1:t){
        s.add(t1.whoid);
    }
    for(task t3:trigger.new){
       iid =t3.whoid;

        }

    for(contact a2:[select id from contact where id=: iid]){
        whoid.add(a2.id);
    }
    list<contact> a=[select phone,name,Email,Mailingcity,Mailingstate,Mailingcountry,Mailingstreet,MailingCountryCode from contact where id in : whoid];
    system.debug(a);
    for(contact a1:a){
        for(task t2:trigger.new){
        string descr = t2.description == null ? 'blank' : t2.description;
        t2.description=descr +' \r\n'+a1.phone + ' \r\n'+a1.name+ ' \r\n'+a1.Mailingcity+ ' \r\n'+a1.Mailingstate+ ' \r\n'+a1.Mailingstreet+' \r\n'+a1.Mailingcountry+  '\r\n'+a1.MailingCountryCode +'\r\n'+a1.email;
        }}
    update t;
}
```

Comment: You've shared the wrong trigger.

Answer (score 1):

As you are running in before insert so you can remove the last DML in your code

```
for(task t2:trigger.new){
        string descr = t2.description == null ? 'blank' : t2.description;
        t2.description=descr +' \r\n'+a1.phone + ' \r\n'+a1.name+ ' \r\n'+a1.Mailingcity+ ' \r\n'+a1.Mailingstate+ ' \r\n'+a1.Mailingstreet+' \r\n'+a1.Mailingcountry+  '\r\n'+a1.MailingCountryCode +'\r\n'+a1.email;
        }}
   // update t;
```

As this will update the description in code with out DML and this will solve your problem.

As per suggestion by sfdcfox you should check other triggers may be they are causing the issue and maybe you have multiple triggers on Task

Or you can put your code in try catch block and using exception method can easily identify where are you getting this error.

```
try {
    //your code here
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug('Exception type caught: ' + e.getTypeName());    
    System.debug('Message: ' + e.getMessage());    
    System.debug('Cause: ' + e.getCause());    // returns null
    System.debug('Line number: ' + e.getLineNumber());    
    System.debug('Stack trace: ' + e.getStackTraceString());    
}
```

The main reason of this error is you can't update `trigger.new` in `after trigger` syntax.

Comment: Realistically, this doesn't answer the problem directly. There's no "after insert" logic happening here, which means a different trigger is the cause of this particular error.

Comment: @sfdcfox update the answer as per suggestion. Thanks.